# Error in migrations after removing image field and upload_to_path method

Tags: django, django-models

I had a field called image in my model.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profile_pic_upload_path)
```

I created the migration for the same and applied it.

After a few more migrations and changes, I decided to remove the field.

I was able to do that and apply the migration as well.

Now I realized I missed deleting the extra `upload_to` method.

When I remove the method from my codebase, I am getting the following error from my initial migration.

```
AttributeError: module 'users.models' has no attribute 'get_profile_pic_upload_path'
```

I see that there a reference to my upload_to method, which is failing.

Now as the field has been removed all together this should not happen.

What is the best way to handle this?

As requested this the end of my error stacktrace:

```
  File "/Users/princearora/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/princearora/code/barbr/barbr_backend/users/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/Users/princearora/code/barbr/barbr_backend/users/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 28, in Migration
    ("image", models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=users.models.get_profile_pic_upload_path)),
AttributeError: module 'users.models' has no attribute 'get_profile_pic_upload_path'
```

Comment: are you sure that you are not using this get_profile_pic_upload_path method anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, checked again using my IDE.
The only usage of the method is in 0001_initial.py migration.

Comment: @ofnowhere can you share the full error log here

Comment: @ShahidTariq added

Comment: Can you try replacing  `upload_to=users.models.get_profile_pic_upload_path` to something like `upload_to='user_images/'` in your migration file(0001_initial.py) and run migrate again

Comment: I can edit the migration file here.
But wanted to understand is the right way to g about it?
Editing older migrations?